# Fortran derived type variable containing pointer fields with the shared attribute inside an OpenMP parallel region

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

I have the following problem: I would like to have access to data that is stored in a derived type with pointer fields. I would like the variable of the derived type to have the "shared" attribute. When running the code I get wrong results. Here is the example:

1. the description of derived type:

   ```
   TYPE, PUBLIC :: T_CSR INTEGER(SIK) :: n
   INTEGER(SIK) :: nval
   REAL(SRK), POINTER :: a(:)
   INTEGER(SIK), POINTER :: ja(:)
   INTEGER(SIK), POINTER :: ia(:)
   INTEGER(SIK), POINTER :: diag(:)
   END TYPE T_CSR
   ```
2. Variable of derived type -

   ```
   type (t_csr):: LU
   ```
3. The code:

   ```
   !$omp parallel do private (ij1, ij2, sum)
   do i = 2, n
     ij1 = LU%ia(i)
     ij2 = LU%diag(i) - 1
     sum = dot_product(LU%a(ij1:ij2), x_vek(LU%ja(ij1:ij2)))
     x_vek(i) = (b_vek(i) - sum)
   end do
   ```

Compiled without openMP or openMP with only one thread - correct results

Compiled with openMP and more then 1 thread - different, wrong result, diverging from correct expected result

Comment: You have a race condition on `x_vek`, i.e. in a given iteration you are reading some elements that are possiby written in other iterations.

Comment: BTW, if your code is a LU decomposition, the iterations depend on each other cannot be parallelized

Comment: Thank you very much! This is definitely the case! This is LU decomposition, does it mean it can't be parallelized at all? Or is there way to do it?

Comment: There certainly exist parallel algorithms for LU decomposition, but I'm quite sure they are non-trivial... The classical, "naive" way is intrisically sequential.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Check tthe short descriptions of the tags you are adding, there is an important remark at the [tag:fortran90] tag.

Comment: If you are trying to write a parallel LU decomposition/ equation solver why not use one of the pre-existing libraries rather than write your own? There's a small industry in parallel direct (and iterative) solvers for sparse systems, why not use one of those?